# How can I install OpenCL on Windows 8 Consumer Preview?

Tags: windows-8-preview, integrated-graphics, intel-core-i3, bitcoin, opencl

I have an Intel Core i3 540. It's got integrated graphics, as far as I know. I'm running the Windows 8 Consumer Preview.

I've wanted to start [mining bitcoins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin_protocol#Bitcoin_mining) for fun, but I've been disappointed with the excruciatingly small amounts I get from simply using my CPU. So I tried to use [BitMinter](https://bitminter.com/). It wanted an OpenCL driver; I downloaded the AMD SDK for [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL). I also downloaded the Intel one and tried that. I didn't get my driver, according to BitMinter. However, under Firefox 4, using the Nokia WebCL extension, http://www.coined.com/ told me that I had both installed; it wouldn't let me use them.

Is there something wrong here? Should I have my driver? Is there an additional set of steps?

Comment: Add your computer make/model or go to device manager and let us know what is listed under "display adapters"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the motherboard onboard graphics you have "Intel HD Graphics"

You need the Intel OpenCL SDK found here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vcsource-tools-opencl-sdk/

Look for a download button near the top right of the page.

Comment: Ah, but that doesn't work - even under all/any of the compatibility modes. This is because, as shown in the title of my question, I am currently running the Windows 8 Consumer Preview.